# "Appearance > Editor" missing from clean WP install

Tags: dashboard

My WordPress dashboard has no "Appearance > Editor" menu option.

I've done a lot of searching, but all of the answers online involve plugins or `define( 'DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true );` having been added to the wp-config.php file. I have no plugins installed yet, and the config file does not have anything about "DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT".

I even tried adding `define( 'DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', false );` into wp-config.php anyway, but it didn't help.

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: It's possible your host disallows it. Worth asking them anyway.

Answer (score 1):

So, I inadvertently solved my own problem by uninstalling WordPress and reinstalling it with Multisite DISABLED. Apparently it's something about Multisite that was causing it to be hidden. Lucky for me, I don't actually need Multisite in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if in any function in the function.php of the theme you're using there isn't the following directive:

```
remove_submenu_page ( 'themes.php', 'theme-editor.php' ); // Appearance-->Editor
```

Comment: Thanks - I didn't actually end up needing to try this, because I reinstalled without Multisite and that fixed it. So apparently it's something related to Multisite.